# Highcharts : chart is not inverted when drilling from a bar chart to a line chart

Tags: charts, highcharts, drilldown

I'm using some different charts renderer in Highcharts drilldown. In some cases, my first level is a column chart and the second (or third...) level is a pie... I have a problem when the first level (for instance) is a bar chart and the second level is a line chart. Indeed, in the second level, the chart is not inverted and the X-axis and Y-axis stay in the same position as for the first level.
You can see an example here : https://jsfiddle.net/vegaelce/f0r1vswn/
I tried to set the inverted properties in the drilldown series without any success

```
            inverted: false,
```

Is there any solution to achieve this dynamically for the drilldown and the drillup action cause I can have up to 3 different levels with different rendering charts on each level ?

Comment: The solution for this issue might be founded on the official Highcharts support forum: https://www.highcharts.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=40961

Comment: Thanks for this information. I tried to implement the solution, it works on 2 drill levels but I have a strange behavior on 3 levels. In the following example https://jsfiddle.net/vegaelce/1xt9kzwu/ the top level is a bar, the second a column chart and the third, a line chart and everything works well. But if the first level is a column, the second a bar and the third is a line, the last level does not diplay correctly. You can switch configuration by changing the invert_chart variable ([true,false,false] for bar>column>line, or [false,true,false] for column>bar>line). Any idea to fix that ?

Comment: could you explain more precisely what is wrong with the last drilldown? It seems to works fine.

Comment: I just changed the chart rendering in level 1 & 2 (lev1 = column - lev2 = bar, instead of lev1 = bar - lev2 = column). The result can be seen here : https://jsfiddle.net/vegaelce/6o17w9nL/ You'll see that the third level is not displayed correctly.

Comment: I think that it is a bug, related to this one - https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/15496 you can add your sample to the thread and ask the core developers for the workaround.